# SQL query for earliest record related to set of rows from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have three tables:

Order: [id, month]

Job: [id, status]

JobOrder: [id, job_id, order_id]

Orders are processed by multiple jobs, and jobs can process orders from multiple months.

I need to select the earliest job to process all orders in each month such that the query returns both the month and the id of the earliest (smallest pk) job to process ALL orders in that month. No matter what I do with GOUP BY queries, I can't seem to figure this one out. How can I do this with a single SQL query and guarantee that the job is related to ALL of the filtered orders?

Comment: Could you provide sample data and expected result based on that set?

Comment: Order has no `status` field. How do you know if an order has been processed?

Comment: Share the expected results and the data in the tables

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok in using subqueries, the below sql can help.

```
SELECT month, Min(job_id) 
FROM   (SELECT month, job_id
        FROM   order_tbl o 
               INNER JOIN joborder jo ON o.id = jo.order_id 
        GROUP  BY month, job_id 
        HAVING Count(DISTINCT order_id) = (SELECT Count(id) 
                                           FROM   order_tbl o1 
                                           WHERE  o1.month = o.month)) sub 
GROUP  BY month;
```

*Refer:* https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6g4qiekAU4i3J8iRoAZiCA/3

Thanks